# (How) can I use Gitlab.com to authenticate against my Angular app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab

I am looking to see how a user, who has authenticated with Gitlab.com, can be authenticated to our Angular website.
I've seen some recommendations to use https://gitlab.com/oauth/applications/
We use gitlab.com for our CI/CD but that doesn't seem particularly noteworthy. Many of the examples I've found are for registering apps with the Enterprise Edition.

cf. [This example](https://cm-gitlab.stanford.edu/help/integration/gitlab.md), [this example](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/gitlab/), and [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html) make it sound promising and possible.

I tried querying gitlab.com with something such as:

```
<a href="https://gitlab.com/authorize?response_type=code
     &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Foauth-redirect&client_id=<provided by gitlab.com>&state=<Not sure where this is explained>">Connect Your Account</a>
```

It seems that the order for the parameters is more important than I'd suspected. A working query was:
`https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<from gitlab>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fredirect&response_type=code&state=bob&scope=profile`

Whereby, `&redirect_uri=` is the URL supplied to gitlab.com
and `state` is some unique value e.g. `state=bob`, `state=hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(1024)).hexdigest()`

Gitlab.com then responds to:

```
http://localhost:4200/oauth-redirect
```

Having create an Angular service i.e. `ng g s oauth-redirect` that return value is then parsed using Angular callback magic, e.g. [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111716/angular-8-how-to-get-data-from-url-in-callback-route)

Current sticking points:

How to appropriately parse and redirect to correct webpage?

Comment: the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#user-owned-applications) walk you through setting up an app. This works with gitlab.com, but you can only use a Group application or a User application, not an Instance-wide application.

Comment: Thanks but looking at the docs - I'm missing how to set up the app. I saw the bit about allowing an app - but that's it. I'm not finding much on this topic beyond some writeups for using proprietary solutions.